# in C++, How to enforce template parameter to be of a scoped enum value type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a class template that I'd like to write as follows:

```
template </*what to put here?*/ T>
Class Bar {};
```

I would like to enforce T to only be a value from a scoped enum.
I used the `is_scoped_enum` type check provided [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_scoped_enum), however the best I was able to come up with was to change `Bar` to be like this:

```
template <typename T>
concept ScopeEnum = is_scoped_enum<T>::value;

template<ScopeEnum SE, SE se>
class Bar {};
```

How can I implement it so `Bar` remains as intended?

Comment: "*I would like to enforce T to only be a value from a scoped enum.*" However, the template parameter of `Bar` is a type rather than a non-type parameter?

Comment: `is_scoped_enum` is C++23, by the way.

Comment: `T` is `typename` in your code.

Answer (score 5):

Use a generic non-type parameter, and constrain its declaration

```
template <ScopedEnum auto se>
class Bar {};
```

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe - In a way, I suppose. Same as all constraints are sfinae turned from hack to proper feature. I assume you are familiar with C++17 allowing placeholder types in non-type parameters. And that C++20 allows constraining the placeholder types with a concept (in every declaration)? This is just that.

Comment: I'm aware..., I didn't realize I was asking you to provide an entire cppreference new page =) Turned from hack to proper. Is indeed true.